# Perl: How do you print the content of 2 arrays, one after the other?

Tags: arrays, perl

Let's say i have 2 arrays.

```
@a1= qw (1, 2, 3);
@a2= qw (a, b, c);
```

How can i print the items from these arrays in the following manner:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
```

Edit: it should be noted that neither the quantity of items nor the content of the arrays is known.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @a1 = qw (1 2 3);
my @a2 = qw (a b c);
print "$a1[$_] $a2[$_]\n" for 0..$#a1;
```

Assuming they are the same length.

Answer (score 3):

Try doing this

```
use Modern::Perl;

my @a1 = qw (1 2 3);
my @a2 = qw (a b c);
say join " ", ($a1[$_], $a2[$_]) for 0..$#a1;
```

(don't put `,` when you use `qw//`)

If you prefer simple old style :

```
my @a1 = qw (1 2 3);
my @a2 = qw (a b c);
print join(" ", ($a1[$_], $a2[$_])) . "\n" for 0..$#a1;
```

Comment: Intresting, thanks :)
Is there any way to do it without a module though?

Comment: @JackPettersson: [`Modern::Perl`](https://metacpan.org/module/Modern::Perl) is unecessary. It mostly just does `use strict`, `use warnings`,and `use 5.010` in a single statement. You should *always* add the first two to anything you write. The last is necessary here because he has chosen to use `say`, which is convenient but by no means necessary: it is the same as `print` but with an implicit newline at the end.

Comment: @JackPettersson : added simple for too

Answer (score 0):

To address the unknown size of the arrays, you could find the length of the array and in a looping structure of your choice you simply print out something like this:

```
//pseudocode

print(array1[0] + array2[0]);
```

You could do so as long as the arrays are of equal length.